Assigning a Video Capture ShortCut to Snagit in Windows
I currently have the Print Screen Shortcut assigned to Capture.
I would like Print Screen to be the Shortcut for Image Capture and Shift+Print Screen to be the shortcut for Video Capture.
I noticed Shortcuts are possible on the Mac but not on Windows?
Shortcuts
I am currently using Snagit 2020:
=== Snagit 2020.0.3.4960 [enu] Diagnostics === System Information: Virtualization: None Windows 10.0 Build 19045

On Windows, print screen already captures the entire screen.

Use ShareX on WIndows, much better app that's also entirelyfree and open source
